# calling a web service from an android application

Tags: android

I am using the following code which i found on internet to call a web service from my android app:

```
public class WebServiceActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/HelloWorld";

    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "HelloWorld";

    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private static final String URL = "http://192.168.1.19/TestWeb/WebService.asmx";


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);



        Button getquote = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getquote);  
        getquote.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  

        public void onClick(View v) { 
            TextView result1;
            result1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.result1);
        try {


            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            EditText CompanyName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.CompanyName); 
            String val1 = (CompanyName.getText().toString());
            request.addProperty("passonString", val1);

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet=true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

            Object result = (Object)envelope.getResponse();

            result1.setText(result.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {

            result1.setText(e.getMessage());
            }
    }
});

}
```

}

I am getting error that application is not responding.I am new in the field , please help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: An ANR happens when some long operation takes place in the "main" thread. This is the event loop thread, and if it is busy, Android cannot process any further GUI events in the application, and thus throws up an ANR dialog..You must go thru this : http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your web service request as a background task. Usually time taken by a network activity is unpredictable. If you use above, the UI Thread will block. That is why it says "Application not responding".

I found this great article.
http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html#concurrency
Have a look at 2. Background Processing

Your example can be modified as following.

```
public class WebServiceActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/HelloWorld";

    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "HelloWorld";

    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private static final String URL = "http://192.168.1.19/TestWeb/WebService.asmx";

    TextView result1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        result1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result1);

        Button getquote = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getquote);
        getquote.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                // push soap request into background.
                new Thread(new Runnable(){

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        doSoapRequest();
                    }

                },"DOINBACKGROUND");
            }
        });

    }

    private void doSoapRequest(){
        try {

            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            EditText CompanyName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.CompanyName);
            String val1 = (CompanyName.getText().toString());
            request.addProperty("passonString", val1);

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                    SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(
                    URL);
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

            Object result = (Object) envelope.getResponse();

//          result1.setText(result.toString());
//           update UI data in a Handler
            Message msg = new Message();
            msg.obj = result.toString();
            result1Handler.sendMessage(msg);
        } catch (Exception e) {

//          result1.setText(e.getMessage());
//           update UI data in a Handler
            Message msg = new Message();
            msg.obj = e.getMessage();
            result1Handler.sendMessage(msg);
        }
    }

    private Handler result1Handler = new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            result1.setText(msg.obj.toString());
        }

    };

}
```

Comment: can you give me some more specific example for ding this using handler , i am finding it little bit hard to understand however i am trying to understand it.

Comment: I have put an example. Try to understand what happens. If you want to see a progressbar while doing above how should it be modified? Hint: Showing a progressbar is also something which should be done in UI Thread.