# How to call Web Service in OnCreate() android

Tags: android

I want to call Web Service for getting some data which has to be displayed in my First screen. I had used in `OnCreate()`, it throws some exception. How to call Web Service in `OnCreate()` method?

Comment: Post your code. What exception is being thrown?

Comment: Please find <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7605866/calling-a-web-service-from-an-android-application"> this</a>, it may help you.

Comment: You should not run long task in life cycle methods or it would raise `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.. Use `AsynTask` for making request to the the web server...

Comment: Do not create network related stuff on the UI thread, create a class which extends AsycTask and handle the network operations here

Comment: You should use AsyncTask or some loaders .. from those backgrounds you have to call the webservice. so that you can fetch and show the contents from webservice

Answer (score 1):

SO you want to call a web service from OnCreate() than use like:

```
String NAMESPACE = "Target Name Sapce/";
String URL = "URL generated in WSDL";
String SOAP_ACTION = "Name Sapce/Method name";
String METHOD_NAME = "Method Name";

//Initialize soap request + add parameters
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);       

//Use this to add parameters
request.addProperty("Parameter1",Parameter1);
request.addProperty("Parameter2",Parameter2);

//Declare the version of the SOAP request
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
try {              
    androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
    //this is the actual part that will call the  
    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
    // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.
    SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
    String validate = result.getProperty(0).toString();

    //Get the first property and change the label text
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected "+result.getProperty(0).toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

} catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This will Help you to call web service from OnCreate() without error.

Answer (score 0):

Whether in `onCreate()` or not, you should not make networking inside the *ui thread*. If you wish to fetch data from web, you can use [this](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) callback based library. Override its `onStart()` to display some 'Please wait...' stuff, and override its `onSuccess()`, `onFailure()` and `onFinish()`(if needed) to continue the execution.